# Separate text at variable words in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, google-spreadsheets

I want to separate Text in a columns in two separate columns.

The columns should separated after following variable `Performance`,`Learning & Growth` and `Business`.

```
| AM                                          | AN                | AO                     |
|---------------------------------------------|-------------------|------------------------|
| Performance       comment                   | Performance       | comment                |
| Learning & Growth        some comment       | Learning & Growth | some comment           |
| Business       This is third comment        | Business          | This is third comment  |
| Performance          This is fourth comment | Performance       | This is fourth comment |
```

I tried **Data Tools** > **Text to Columns**. But this isn't working in `Learning & Growth` row.

Thank you for your time and consideration

**Edit:**
I am able to split **Upper Text** of comment using below formula

`=TRIM(LEFT(AM2, SEARCH(CHAR(10),AM2,1)-1)))`

But I am not able to split **Lower Text**

`=RIGHT(AM2,LEN(AN2)-FIND(" ",AM2))`

This is giving me **Value Error**

Comment: Welcome to Super User please [edit] your post and be specific about your need since you want to split text at variable words,, is uncommon,, also has variable length.

Comment: @RajeshS, I have updated my question please check.

Comment: To make it common you [edit] post & set criteria Performance, Learning and Business !

Comment: Have you tried setting the text to columns delimiter to either tab or fixed width?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HYG a way to do it with forumlas:

1. Replace any space within your variables with an underscore, hash, or
   any unique character. Example: the variable "Learning & Growth"
   should be "Learning_&_Growth"
2. This can be done by CTRL + H > in **Find what** box type "**Learning
   & Growth"**, and in **Replace with** box type
   **"Learning_&_Growth"**.
3. Assuming text to be split is in column A. Put the below formula in
   an adjacent column

> `=LEFT(A1, SEARCH(" ",A1,1)-1)`

4. Put the below formula in the next adjacent column

> `=RIGHT(A1,(LEN(A1)-FIND(" ",A1)))`

5. The 1st formula will extract the variable name, as it extracts any
   characters before the 1st space.
6. The 2nd formula will extract the text after the variable name as
   required.